# How to tie zk components to objects or variables?

Tags: events, components, zk, zul

Say I have a zul page like so:

```
<zk>
<tree id="tree1">
<tree id="tree2">
</zk>
```

I need to create an object which can be set to different zk components depending on conditions. The conditions could be events, for example:

If a treerow of tree1 is clicked ---> set the value of object to tree1 --> then I should be able to access the object i.e. tree1 from multiple java classes and modify it
If a treerow of tree2 is clicked ---> set the value of object to tree1 --> then I should be able to access the object i.e. tree1 from multiple java classes and modify it

What is the best approach to achieve this task? Maybe I can set an object in Desktop and use it, but I am not sure how to do this. Can someone point me to suitable documentation or examples?

Thanks,
Sony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference to ZK document  [Inter-Page_Communication](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Guide/ZK_in_Depth/Inter_Page,_App_Communication/Inter-Page_Communication) .

You could use setAttribute / getAttribute to share datas , 
it's available for all components and desktops.